# Is there a case where the "unsafe" keyword and the "unsafe" compilation option are NOT used together?

Tags: c#, compilation, unsafe

From what I've read the `unsafe keyword` is used to make a piece of code (method, etc.) as "unsafe", allowing for pointer logic to be used.

And if you have that keyword in your code it will not compile, unless you specify the `unsafe compilation option`.

And the `unsafe compilation option` is there to be used if your code has unsafe code.

So, this looks redundant. You can't compile unsafe code without the `unsafe compilation option` and you only use the `unsafe compilation option` in you have the `unsafe keyword` in your code.

Since the `unsafe keyword` does not imply the `unsafe compilation option` or turn it on automatically I wonder - is there any case or event where each of those two things can be used separately?

I.e. unsafe code compiling without the compiler option or code, specified with that option that doesn't have unsafe code not need it?

Comment: No. As soon as you have one, you need the other. The reason, in my opinion, that this isn't set automatically is that unsafe code can create issues with stability and security, due to its inherent complex syntax and potential for memory related errors, so to force the developer to be vigilant building/shipping the code, he is forced to manually set the unsafe compilation option

Comment: You could allow unsafe code and then not make use of that option.

Comment: It is of course not a matter of 'needing', the compile option is a safety catch at the project level. A red flag.

Comment: @bommelding I can also have money and not buy anything with it, but it seems pointless.